# jsdoc typedef based on real const

Tags: jsdoc

for example i have const and typedef for it

```js
/**@typedef {{key1:string,key2:string,key3:string}} optionsType*/
const options = {
  key1: "val1",
  key2: "val2",
  key3: "val3"
};
```

and then i want write function that require any key fo "options" object as parameter

```js
/**
 * @param {keyof optionsType} key
 */
function func(key){
/* ... */
 return 0
}
```

but later, if i want change pool of available keys i need to change object itself and typedef for it.

Is it possible to avoid that and declare type based on object itself?

Comment: TypeScript can do this with inferencing, I think inferencing goes against the philosophy of jsdocs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Take a look at the following snippet.

```js
const options = {
  key1: "val1",
  key2: "val2",
  key3: "val3"
};

/**
 * @typedef {typeof options} optionsType
 */
```

In between `{` and `}` in the `@typedef` you can write any valid typescript code.